# only mine albums are showing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php

    require_once 'src/facebook.php';
    try{
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'my app id',
                'secret' => 'my secret key',
                'cookie' => true
        ));
        if(is_null($user=$facebook->getUser()))
        {
                header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'))}");
                exit;
        }
     $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo '<p>Please try clearing your browser cookies or <a href="">click here</a>.</p>';
        die;
    }
if($user) {
    $albums = $facebook->api("/me?fields=albums");
       echo " <form action='53.php' method='GET'>
        <select name='album_id' onchange=\"showAlbum(this.value)\">
        <option type='hidden' value=0>Select an album</option>";
        foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
            echo "<option type='hidden' value='".$album['id']."'> ".$album['name']."</option>";

        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type="SUBMIT"  name="down" value="SUBMIT"></form></div>';
}  
?>
```

I have created an app on facebook . I am using PHP language . My Probem is this when i logged in , it shows me the album name in dropdown but when another user logged in , it still showing me my albums only . where i am doing wrong ?? please help me so that i am able to get other user album in my dropdown , when the user logged in

Comment: It must be the way you're logging the user out of your application. How are you logging the previous user out?